# Python Access Count Generator Triggered by __str__()?

Tags: python

This is a very minor point, but would be nice to know.
I am looking to simplify some reporting code that generally looks like this:

```
i = 0
for e in clist:
    log.info(u'Processing record {:,} of {:,}.'.format(i, len(clist)))
    i += 1
    # ... do something
```

a bit ugly right?

Is there a built in class that will yield the next integer so I can do this:

```
i = IntegerGenerator(0) 
for e in clist:
    log.info(u'Processing record {:,} of {:,}.'.format(i, len(clist)))
    # ... do something
```

or should I just write it myself by defining a generator with a custom `__str__` method?
Admittedly the whole point is to get rid of the `i += 1`.

Comment: I need it to count how many times it is 'used'.  In this case used means that someone asked it to be a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, e in enumerate(clist):
    log.info(u'Processing record {:,} of {:,}.'.format(i, len(clist)))
```

`enumerate()` yields tuples with `(index, item)` for items in the passed-in sequence.

If you needed to create counts *independent* of the list, you could use [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count); each time you pass a `count()` object to the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) it'll yield the next value in the series:

```
from itertools import count

i = count()

for e in clist:
    if some_condition:
        log.info(u'Processing record {:,} of {:,}.'.format(next(i), len(clist)))
```

Now `i` is only incremented each time `some_condition` is true.